# Force links to be opened inside my application

Tags: android, hyperlink

In my application I have some TextViews that have links to some websites in them. Currently when user clicks on them the website is being opened in the default browser like Chrome but I would like to force them to open inside my application in the webview. Can it somehow be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a web view Activity/Fragment.

You can define the widget in your layout

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/myWebview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And open the selected link from your activity

```
WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

Refer to [Android Developer web view](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#java)

Comment: Yes but after clicking the link it still can be opened in external browser. I would like to force it to open in that webview

Comment: i suppose that you are starting e new activity with an Intent like this Intent `browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));`
`startActivity(browserIntent);`

Comment: Thats not his question

Comment: Why not? He is using the intent to start the brower but he wants to open the link in-app. To reach this he should use web view

Comment: read these words in his question "open inside my application in the webview".

Comment: Words preceded by "I would like to force them to [...]" and "when user clicks on them (textView) the website is being opened in the default browser like Chrome" that means he didn't implemented the webview

Answer (score -1):

Try to set `WebViewClient`.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```